# mysql FUNCTION stores.ST_Intersects does not exist

Tags: mysql, geometry

I am trying to set a value isInside as if user geoLocation is inside one of any shapes inside the table, i am doing this query

```
function getNearMe( $lat = 0 , $lng = 0  , $withDistance = 120)
{

   try{ 
         $q = $this->api->pdo->prepare("SELECT * ,
                                        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( store_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( store_longitude ) - radians($lng) ) + 
                                        sin( radians($lat) ) *
                                         sin( radians( store_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance,
                                         ST_Intersects(Point($lng,$lat),`gps`)  AS isInside
                                        FROM stores 
                                        " . ( $withDistance == 0 ? "" : " HAVING distance < $withDistance " ) ." 
                                        ORDER BY distance
                                        ");

          $q->execute();

          return $q->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

       }catch( PDOException $e ){
        print_r($e);
       return array();
    }
}
```

> ST_Intersects(Point($lng,$lat),`gps`)  AS isInside

here is the table

[image]

but i am getting this Error :

> FUNCTION stores.ST_Intersects does not exist

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes i know the $lng , $lat and $withDistance is added to PDO binds

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution might help someone else

```
MBRContains(gps,
GeomFromText('Point($lat $lng)')) AS isInside
```